# A series involve combination

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, education

I want find another Idea to find sum of $\left(\begin{array}{c}n+3\\ 3\end{array}\right)$ from $n=1 ,to,n=47$ 
or $$\sum_{n=1}^{47}\left(\begin{array}{c}n+3\\ 3\end{array}\right)=?$$ I do it first by turn $\left(\begin{array}{c}n+3\\ 3\end{array}\right)$ to $\dfrac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{3!}=\dfrac16 (n^3+6n^2+11n+6)$ and find sum of them by separation  $$\sum i=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\\\sum i^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\\sum i^3=(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$$ 
then I think more and do like below ... 
I think there is more Idea to find this summation .

please hint, thanks in advanced

Comment: The [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) might be useful.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh : hardly remember from discreet mathematics ,there was a way to find this sum (and like this )

Comment: You can write ( with $\LaTeX$ or/and $\texttt{MathJax}$ ), ${n + 3 \choose 3}$ as $\texttt{{n + 3 \choose 3}}$ or/and $\texttt{\binom{n + 3}{3}}$. You don't need the $\texttt{array}$ environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the well known [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{47}\binom{n+3}{3} = \binom{47+3+1}{3+1} $$
and the problem is trivial from there.

Answer (score 2):

This was my second try :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{47}\left(\begin{array}{c}n+3\\ 3\end{array}\right)=\\
\dfrac16\sum_{n=1}^{47}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=\\
\dfrac16.\dfrac14\sum_{n=1}^{47}(\color{red} {n+4-n})(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)=\\
\dfrac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^{47}(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)-(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n\\
\\by  \space {[f(n)=(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n]}\\
\dfrac{1}{24}\sum_{n=1}^{47}f(n+1)-f(n)\\
\dfrac{1}{24}(f(48)-f(1))$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{47}{n + 3 \choose  3} & =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{k}
\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{k}{n + 3 \choose  n}} =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose  n}\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{k = n}^{\infty}z^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose  n}\pars{-1}^{n}{z^{n} \over 1 - z} =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}\bracks{{1 \over 1 - z}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose  n}\pars{-z}^{n}}
\\[5mm] & =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}\bracks{{1 \over 1 - z}\,\pars{1 - z}^{-4}} =
-1 + \bracks{z^{47}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-5 \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k} =
-1 - {-5 \choose 47}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\ds{-1 + {51 \choose 47}}} =
-1 + {51 \times 50 \times 49 \times 48 \over 4 \times 3 \times 2} =
\bbx{\ds{249899}}
\end{align}

Comment: Martin : What do you mean for $\left[Z^{47}\right]$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash It's a notation. Namely, $\left[z^{\ell}\right]\,\mathrm{f}\left(z\right)$ is the coefficient of $z^{\ell}$ in the expansion of $\,\mathrm{f}\left(z\right)$ in powers of $z$.